# Cowrie as a decoy on production server: is it a good idea?

Tags: ssh, honeypot

I'm considering setting up a SSH honeypot listening on port 22 on my production servers. I'm hoping that not getting an immediate `Connection refused` would slow down potential attackers.

[image: illustration of the setup : cowrie listens on port 22 and ssh listens on port 982]

Are there any security issues with this setup?

Comment: Ideally, for a production server, you'd limit SSH access to specific source IP addresses (e.g. from an office, or known VPN), and use certificate based authentication. Are these not options in this case?

Comment: The actual SSH access has to be as limited as possible, you are absolutely right. But, assuming it is, I'm wondering about the consequences of adding a fake insecure one (e.g. i'll have to expose port 22)

Comment: Please read the dev's own FAQ on t his very question: https://github.com/micheloosterhof/cowrie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: wow, thank you. That pretty much answers my question. Sorry I missed it. Maybe you can turn your comment into an answer ?

Comment: You could always do some creative firewalling to make it _look like_ it's on the same machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom-coded honeypots should ***not*** be run on production servers. Honeypots are meant to gather data, but are not meant to be unbreakable. [The Dev for Cowrie says in his FAQ](https://github.com/micheloosterhof/cowrie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> However, Cowrie has not had any real security audit done on it, and
>   it's definitely vulnerable to some DoS attacks, as there are no limits
>   on how many people can connect to it, or how many files they can
>   download.
>
> It's my recommendation to run Cowrie on a dedicated well firewalled
>   Virtual Machine as the non-root user.

There are types of honeypots that are a reconfigured production service, and you might use those on production servers because the threat is no lower than running the production service.

You have to remember that you are inviting people with nefarious motives into your server. Whatever tools you give them will be used against you. The general advice is to keep the honeypots segregated and automatically refreshed on a regular basis so that it does not become a launching pad for the attacker.

Comment: Note to self: RTFM.